# What is the name and the purpose of the design pattern with 3 classes inside of an interface?

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, proxy, stub

What is please the name and the purpose of the design pattern used in the following interface [mindroid/os/IRemoteCallback.java](https://github.com/Himmele/Mindroid.java/blob/master/src/mindroid/os/IRemoteCallback.java)?

Why are there 3 classes (`Stub`, `Proxy`, `SmartProxy`) defined inside the interface?

```
public interface IRemoteCallback extends IInterface {
    public static abstract class Stub extends Binder implements IRemoteCallback {
        private static final String DESCRIPTOR = "mindroid.os.IRemoteCallback";

        public Stub() {
            this.attachInterface(this, DESCRIPTOR);
        }

        public static IRemoteCallback asInterface(IBinder binder) {
            if (binder == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return new IRemoteCallback.Stub.SmartProxy(binder);
        }

        public IBinder asBinder() {
            return this;
        }

        protected Object onTransact(int what, int arg1, int arg2, Object obj, Bundle data) throws RemoteException {
            switch (what) {
            case MSG_SEND_RESULT: {
                sendResult(data);
                return null;
            }
            default:
                return super.onTransact(what, arg1, arg2, obj, data);
            }
        }

        private static class Proxy implements IRemoteCallback {
            private final IBinder mRemote;

            Proxy(IBinder remote) {
                mRemote = remote;
            }

            public IBinder asBinder() {
                return mRemote;
            }

            public void sendResult(Bundle data) throws RemoteException {
                mRemote.transact(MSG_SEND_RESULT, data, FLAG_ONEWAY);
            }
        }

        private static class SmartProxy implements IRemoteCallback {
            private final IBinder mRemote;
            private final IRemoteCallback mStub;
            private final IRemoteCallback mProxy;

            SmartProxy(IBinder remote) {
                mRemote = remote;
                mStub = (IRemoteCallback) remote.queryLocalInterface(DESCRIPTOR);
                mProxy = new IRemoteCallback.Stub.Proxy(remote);
            }

            public IBinder asBinder() {
                return mRemote;
            }

            public void sendResult(Bundle data) throws RemoteException {
                if (mRemote.runsOnSameThread()) {
                    mStub.sendResult(data);
                } else {
                    mProxy.sendResult(data);
                }
            }
        }

        static final int MSG_SEND_RESULT = 1;
    }

    public void sendResult(Bundle data) throws RemoteException;
}
```

I have difficulties to understand and use the above code.

The only thing I have noticed is the check if the caller is at the same thread and if not - a message is sent via handler to the `Proxy` class.

Also I think that a String (here `DESCRIPTOR` constant) can be used across different Threads to get ahold of an [IInterface](https://github.com/Himmele/Mindroid.java/blob/master/src/mindroid/os/IInterface.java).

**UPDATE:**

Here reply by the author:

> It is about having the Callback run in the correct thread context, which is
>   the context that created the callback.
>   The SmartProxy class first checks if it a thread-local call or a remote
>   (inter-thread) call.
>   Then is either calls the method directly (using the Stub) or it does
>   message passing to switch to the right thread context (using Proxy).

Comment: That's no design pattern, unfortunately. It's simply a mess of code nested together.

Comment: No, there must be a reason why this pattern is used throughout several interface files: [IRemoteCallback.java](https://github.com/Himmele/Mindroid.java/blob/master/src/mindroid/os/IRemoteCallback.java), [IOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.java](https://github.com/Himmele/Mindroid.java/blob/master/src/mindroid/app/IOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.java), [IPackageManagerListener.java](https://github.com/Himmele/Mindroid.java/blob/master/src/mindroid/content/pm/IPackageManagerListener.java), etc.

Comment: The author of the code may think he's using some pattern, or may have attempted to invent one; but there is no documented design pattern implemented here. You can see that the complexity introduced by the levels of nested inheritance inspires nonsense such as the `asBinder()` method. You wouldn't find such a mess in a formal design pattern. I'm afraid that only the author could explain the intent behind this code.

Comment: There may be a *reason*, but that doesn't imply that it constitutes a known design pattern  with a *name*.